# How to Create A Termbase without Creating Project in MemoQ?

Tags: translation, machine-translation, study-of-terms

Well, there was no platform on StackExchange for translation or translators, so I thought asking here is okay.

As in title, is there a way to create a termbase and adding to it without creating a project in MemoQ 2015?

Comment: And also, where to suggest a platform to Stackexchange would help.

Comment: For me, asking questions about "Applied Linguistics" (like translation or terminology) is perfectly fine here.

Comment: Questions about how to use software can go to http://superuser.com

Comment: @Eray Erdin That would be Area51.